# Animate size increase in increments, animation is only smooth on first increment, flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, dart

I am having some problems with an animation I'm trying to do in Flutter using Dart. I am trying to incrementally increase the height of a box when the user clicks a button. Below is a very simple example of what I am trying to achieve.  My problem is that the smooth animation only works for the first click but after that there is no animation, the box only gets larger.
Is there a way to fix this problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Size Animation'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  double _myHeight = 310;
  double _counter = 30;
  double _target = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Reset me'),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  _target = 10;
                  _animationController.reset();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Click me'),
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_target < _myHeight) {
                    setState(() {
                      _target += _counter;
                    });
                  }
                  _animationController.forward();
                },
              ),
              AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _animationController,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 80,
                      height: _animationController.value * _target,
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily reach this just by having a simple AnimatedContainer, that will automatically animate itself whenever one of it's proprierties changes, so your widget would look like this:

```
AnimatedContainer(
   duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
   color: Colors.green,
   width: 80,
   height: _target
)
```

That way when `_target` value changes with setState value, your widget would animate the height.

Your current animation is working only the first time, because actually your are just running the `animationController` only once, then you recall the `forward()` again and again, but your animation has already been animated so, there's no forward, the value is going from 0 to 1 only the first time, then everytime you call the `forward()` method the animation is already at value 1, so you see no animation. One way you could do that if you really wanna keep this animation with an `AnimatedBuilder` you should give it a `Tween` instead of your `animationController`

Comment: My sample code uses a container for simplicity's sake. I have SizedBoxes in a Stack in the real application. I had started to look at Tween but you got me thinking with your suggested solution and I can actually redo the application with Animated container at the heart of it, much simpler :)

Comment: Flutter has a lot widgets that can handle simple animation like this, take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXIJJkq_H8g) to learn how to select the right animation widget and when you should use your own custom animation.